# При клике на ссылку открыть страницу и показать определенный таб

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть сайт с меню. в этом меню при наведении на ссылку выпадает подменю с заголовками табов.(контент самих табов находится на другой странице). Как сделать чтобы при клике в подменю на ссылку с заголовком определенного таба  переходило на страницу с табами и открывало этот таб?

Comment: передайте хеш в урле и по нему определяйте какой таб  открывать при загрузке страницы
 например так
http://site.ru/stranica#tab1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно при клике на ссылку записывать значение в localStorage, a на странице с табами вытаскивать и открывать таб.

Ссылка в меню:

```
<a class="menu-link" data-tab="#tab-1" href="">Меню 1</a>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var key = 'clicked-tab' ;
    jQuery('a.menu-link').on('click', function(){        
        localStorage.setItem(key, jQuery(this).data('tab'));
    });

    if (true) {   //добавляем условие "если на странице с табами"
        //селектор для таба
        jQuery('a[href='+localStorage.getItem(key)+']').click();
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
});
```